# How to use one array in multiple classes?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am definitely doing something wrong here. I created a program and a class. Here is the program code I have written so far:

```
public class CashRegisterViewModel: Cash
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       double amountdue = 100;
        double amountpaid = 1650;
        Cash register = new Cash();


        for( double i = amountpaid; i < 0; i--)
        {
            register.Cash ;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code I have written for the Cash class, where I control the "Cash Register" part of the code:

```
static void Register()
    {
        double[] cashmoney = { 100, 50, 230, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
        Array.Sort(cashmoney);
        Array.Reverse(cashmoney);

    }

    int index = cashmoney.Length();
```

So far so good? Not quite. Despite it being only a few lines of code, I have encountered several problems already:

- I can't use the Array.Length() function in the cash class
- I seemingly can't call the array in the program, since it "Doesn't exist"

And that's it, for now. I am pretty new to Csharp, so I think I missed some vital information while creating the class.

Comment: Your view model shouldn't inherit from the Cash class. It can new up a Cash object to manipulate, but the view model isn't a Cash object.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You may have *some* idea of what you expect e.g. the line `register.Cash;` to do in that loop, I have no idea.

Comment: Please paste the `Cash`class in your question, or describe your intent. So we only see, you're doing something wrong, but not what your purpose is :-) Starting by a class named `viewmodel` having a `static Main()` looks somehow weird :-)

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `cashmoney.Length()` outside of the scope where you declared the array. Also Length is a property so you can't call it like a method. You are declaring the array in the `Register` method, so the variable is only available there.

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes), to learn more about scopes.

You could create a property in the `Cash` class called `Cashmoney`, like this:

```
public double[] Cashmoney {get; set;}
```

That way you can access that property from outside. Learn more about properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties)

Comment: `Array.Length` is a property, not a method.

Comment: What does that even have to do with my answer? :D

Comment: Well, `cashmoney.Length()` wouldn't even compile...

Comment: Ah, I see, I'll update my answer then, but to be fair I think @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment sums it up pretty well